# The present paper VS the current paper

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, semantics, writing-advice

I am writing an article. I wonder if the two following expressions are equivalent when I refer to the article and compare it with another article? or is there any semantic difference between them?

-The current paper

-The present paper

I searched on web and it seems that they are perfectly the same.

Comment: I would only understand the second as the paper that I am holding in my hand.

Comment: "Current" has the additional meaning of "most recent", while "present" can mean "physically present" (whether in hand or on screen), so the terms are similar but not identical. Both could potentially refer to a paper already being discussed (e.g. in a review). But if you're contrasting them with something else ("e.g. the present paper looks at X, while Smith's paper looks at Y"), that will make it clearer what you're referring to. "This paper" is another convenient way of expressing the same thing.

Comment: Within the paper, refer to it as "the present paper".  That is what I have seen (maybe even used?)